# Get table name form a model

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

So I have a model like this

```
Qber.V1.CustomerModel
```

this is store in my code in the variable queryable

```
defp build_select(queryable, opts_select \\ []) do
  case opts_select do
    nil -> 
      queryable
    IO.inspect opts_select
    select when is_list(select) ->
      IO.inspect select
      map =  Enum.map(select, &String.to_existing_atom/1)
      IO.inspect map  
      a =  from queryable, select: ^map
      IO.inspect a
   end
end
```

Now when I run the query it maps the select to the whole model but what I want is **customers** table like this instead of whole `Qber.V1.CustomerModel`

How can I do this?

Comment: The question is - why do you need the table name? Ecto queries are working against data structs anyway.

Comment: because when using the model. the select is not working it maps the select to the whole model and return all the fields.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
model = queryable
    IO.inspect model
    Map.values(model.__struct__.__meta__)
    [Ecto.Schema.Metadata, nil, {nil, table_name}, :built] = Map.values(model.__struct__.__meta__)
    table = table_name
```

So i implemented it like this.

Comment: A map is not ordered so relying on the order of the return value of `Map.values` is not a good idea. Try `{nil, table_name} = model.__struct__.__meta__.source` instead.

Comment: Whilst code only answers may solve the original problem, some explanation would help a lot in understanding the method you've used and how it works.

Answer (score 0):

If understand you correctly, you have 2 tables:

- `customer_models`
- `customers`

And you want to use `customers` to fetch data using model `Qber.V1.CustomerModel`.

If so then Ecto 2.x have support for that via

```
from customer in {"customers", Qber.V1.CustomerModel}, …
```

Comment: @hammadahmed then reword your question with example of what you want to accomplish. Because your code isn't helping much.